# Why did Zabuza kill that year's graduating class?

Tags: naruto

In *Naruto*, Kakashi mentions the graduation exam in the Hidden Mist Village used to be to pit two students to fight to the death, then he says Zabuza, a boy who was not even a ninja at the time, slaughtered a year's graduating class in the Hidden Mist Village.

I've always thought Zabuza looks kind of sad in the image shown:

[image: Young Zabuza amongst bodies]

Zabuza gives a psychotic reason ("It felt so good"), but to me, it seems like there's some missing part of the story, something we're not being told, due to the posture Zabuza's taking here, Zabuza's own words about what it means to be a ninja, and also similar lies told by other characters in the story.

> Such as Itachi and Gaara's uncle.

It makes me curious about what his motivation was. Is it ever explained why Zabuza did this in any of the various media?